# Gravity Forms - Organizing a conditional logic, two column layout with section breaks

Tags: css, wordpress, e-commerce, customization, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm creating an online ordering system using Gravity Forms for a restaurant. Most of the menu choices on the menu give the ability to select different add-ons or options.

I have configured the menu items as radio buttons, so once they are clicked they open a section where you can select the options you want. I have a couple rows of menu items that are two by two, and another couple that are three by three.

The issue I am running into is that when the options sections are opened up, they open on top of eachother. I would like them to stay in their columns underneath the menu items that they are linked with.

Is this possible using standard gravity forms or do I need to make some CSS modifications? If so, how to do?

Comment: Could you give us a link to the form? Seeing it in action will help us troubleshoot the issue a lot more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make some CSS modifications. What I do is remove all default gravity forms styling and change the elements to HTML5. This is all in the settings and then you can recreate the form styling.

This github is a really great resource and has everything you will need to help you with the styling.

https://github.com/thatryan/gravity-forms-sass